# Compare numbers in array

Tags: java, arrays, compare

I have an array with two elements in java.

How do I best decide if I should add theese or just chose one of them (which?) in order to get as close to 1000 as possible?

I am defenetly doing something wrong, it always adds the two numbers!

```
    if(myArray.length==2){
        int a = 1000-(myArray[0]);
        int b = 1000-(myArray[1]);
        int c = 1000-(myArray[0]+myArray[1]);

        if( (1000-a) < (1000-b)){
            if((a+b)<1000){
                bestAnswer = myArray[0]+myArray[1];
                }
                else{
                    bestAnswer = myArray[0];
                }
            }


        if( (1000-a) > (1000-b)){   
            if((a+b)<1000){
                bestAnswer = myArray[0]+myArray[1];
            }
                else{
                    bestAnswer = myArray[0];
                }
            }
        else{
            if((1000-(myArray[0]+myArray[1]))<(1000-(myArray[0]))){
                bestAnswer = myArray[0]+myArray[1];
            }
            else{
                bestAnswer = myArray[0];
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you give some examples and output expectations?

Comment: sure. if the first element is 10 and the other is 20, we have to add them to get as close to 1000 as possible. If one would be 999 and the other 34 , we only need the first, 999. Note: none of the elements in the array can be more than 1000!

Comment: @SofiaEmilsson, why would there be a limitation such that { 999, 1010 } is an invalid input? In that case the answer would be 999. The limitation is that *all* elements cannot be more than 1000, isn't it?

Comment: in theory yes, but my instructions says: "each element in the array is a positive integer less than or equal to 1000"

Comment: @SofiaEmilsson, ah, you were adding requirements in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the absolute value of *c* to catch the use case where *c* is over 1000.

```
int a = 1000-(myArray[0]);
int b = 1000-(myArray[1]);
int c = Math.abs(1000-(myArray[0]+myArray[1]));         

if( a < Math.min(b, c)) {
    bestAnswer = myArray[0];
}
else if(b < Math.min(a, c)) {
    bestAnswer = myArray[1];
}
else {
    bestAnswer = myArray[0]+myArray[1];
}
```

Comment: I'll delete my answer, didn't think about the case where the `int`s added up would be over 1000. However keep in mind, according to his comment apparently none of the `int`s in the array can be over 1000. So you would only need to use absolute value for the addition.

Comment: I also noticed that it put together the two, if they where the same int. I corrected that by writing <= insted og just < in the comparisions. Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: could this solution work for n number of elements, instead of only 2? how whould that look?

Answer (score 1):

Given both integers positive and less than or equal to 1000, this should work.

```
myArray[0] = 80;
myArray[1] = 90
int c = myArray[0] + myArray[1];

bestAnswer = myArray[0]; // 80

if (myArray[1] > myArray[0]) { // 90 > 80? Yes.
    bestAnswer = myArray[1]; // bestAnswer = 90
} 
if (c > myArray[1] && c <= 1000) { // 170 > 90? Yes.
    bestAnswer = c; // 170 = bestAnswer.
}
```

Comment: it looks good in the second if, but what if myArray[0]=999 and myArray[1]=800? then 999 should be seleted, but in this algorithm 800 is...?

Comment: Not sure why you would think that. Test it and see for yourself.

Comment: but what I intended to say is, what if (myArray[1] > myArray[0]) = true, but they still has to be added together in order to come as close to 1000 as possible? now, if myArray[1] > myArray[0] then myArray[1]  is selected

Comment: Yes, myArray[1] = bestAnswer AT FIRST. But this will not be the case anymore after the second if statement. The code doesn't terminate after the first if statement. 

Please try out the code in the IDE of your choice and you will see that it works.

Comment: 200, -999 fails it returns -799 when it should be 200. then again she did say only positive numbers but eh

Comment: @BrandonLing The integers are positive - specified in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class TestMain2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 12;
        int b = 990;
        System.out.println(check(a,b));
    }

    public static String check(int a, int b) {
        String result = null;

        int aPlusBDiff = Math.abs(1000 - a - b);
        int aDiff = Math.abs(1000 - a);
        int bDiff = Math.abs(1000 - b);

        int min = Math.min(Math.min(aDiff, bDiff), aPlusBDiff);

        if(aPlusBDiff == min) {
            result = "Add both";
        } else if(aDiff == min) {
            result = "Choose A";
        } else {
            result = "Choose B";
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more condensed version

```
 public static int getClosestToThousand(int a, int b) {
    int closestSoFar = Math.abs(a - 1000) < Math.abs(b - 1000) ? a : b;
    return Math.abs(closestSoFar - 1000) < Math.abs(a + b - 1000) ? closestSoFar : a + b;
}
```